# logstash filter to modify array field

Tags: arrays, json, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am looking for a logstash filter that can modify array fields.

For example, I would like a modifier that can turn this JSON document

```
{
  arrayField: [
    {
      subfield: {
        subsubfield: "value1"
      }
    },
    {
      subfield: {
        subsubfield: "value2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Into this JSON document

```
{
  arrayField: [
    {
      subfield: "value1"
    },
    {
      subfield: "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the following input

```
input {
  mutate {
    replace => ["[arrayField][subfield]", "%{[arrayField][subField][subsubField]}"]
  }
}
```

but the input just rewrites the array field instead of operating on each element of the array. How do you set up a modifier to operate on each element of an array?

Comment: To generically loop across fields in logstash, you'll need to drop into the ruby{} filter.  There are examples of this in other SO posts.

Comment: Thanks, the ruby filter worked great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Alain Collins for pointing out the ruby filter. The below input did the trick.

```
input {
  ruby {
    code => "
      event['arrayField'].each{|subdoc| subdoc['subfield'] = subdoc['subfield']['subsubfield']}
    "
  }
}
```